# Android: web services

Tags: android, web-services

I want to create an Android App (client-server) that will interact with already running web server.

I have decided to use `REST` as opposed to `SOAP`.

Here are my 2 questions:

**1** .What data format is more reliable and simple to use? `JSON` or `Open Data protocol (odata.org)` ?
**2**. How do I make the first communication between the server and the app?

I need to call the server, and then get a response (just to test the connection).
Please include some code as an example or a link to where I can lern more!

Comment: You should try atleast something for "Just to test the connection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definately go with JSON as it is more commonly used. As for designing RESTful apps on android I would start with [Android RESTful](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) to see the general concept and would take a look at those code bits that helped me out: [Android RESTful API Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service)

Comment: thanks.. links were really helpful. Can u give me some other resource where i can get some basic information of android web services.. just basic and beginner web service information! Thanks

Comment: With JSON and REST it is probably best to just use HTTPClient as Paresh noted below. Please take note that in newer version of android it is recommended to use [HttpUrlConnection in general over HttpClient](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html). Some nice, comprehensive info on using JAX-RS with Android is available [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/x-android-jax-rs/index.html?ca=drs-)

Answer (score 1):

calling RESTful web service

```
public class RestClient {
private boolean authentication;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> headers;

private String jsonBody;
private String message;

private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
private String response;
private int responseCode;

private String url;

// HTTP Basic Authentication
private String username;
private String password;

protected Context context;

public RestClient(String url) {
    this.url = url;
    params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
}
//Be warned that this is sent in clear text, don't use basic auth unless you have to.
public void addBasicAuthentication(String user, String pass) {
    authentication = true;
    username = user;
    password = pass;
}

public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
    headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

public void addParam(String name, String value) {
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

public void execute(RequestMethod method)
    throws Exception {
    switch (method) {
        case GET: {
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + addGetParams());
            request = (HttpGet) addHeaderParams(request);
            executeRequest(request, url);
            break;
        }
        case POST: {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request = (HttpPost) addHeaderParams(request);
            request = (HttpPost) addBodyParams(request);
            executeRequest(request, url);
            break;
        }
        case PUT: {
            HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
            request = (HttpPut) addHeaderParams(request);
            request = (HttpPut) addBodyParams(request);
            executeRequest(request, url);
            break;
        }
        case DELETE: {
            HttpDelete request = new HttpDelete(url);
            request = (HttpDelete) addHeaderParams(request);
            executeRequest(request, url);
        }
    }
}

private HttpUriRequest addHeaderParams(HttpUriRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    for (NameValuePair h : headers) {
        request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
    }

    if (authentication) {

        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                username, password);
        request.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, request));
    }

    return request;
}

private HttpUriRequest addBodyParams(HttpUriRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    if (jsonBody != null) {
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        if (request instanceof HttpPost)
            ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonBody,
                    "UTF-8"));
        else if (request instanceof HttpPut)
            ((HttpPut) request).setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonBody,
                    "UTF-8"));

    } else if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        if (request instanceof HttpPost)
            ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,
                    HTTP.UTF_8));
        else if (request instanceof HttpPut)
            ((HttpPut) request).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,
                    HTTP.UTF_8));
    }
    return request;
}

private String addGetParams()
    throws Exception {
    StringBuffer combinedParams = new StringBuffer();
    if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        combinedParams.append("?");
        for (NameValuePair p : params) {
            combinedParams.append((combinedParams.length() > 1 ? "&" : "")
                    + p.getName() + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
    }
    return combinedParams.toString();
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public int getResponseCode() {
    return responseCode;
}

public void setContext(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

public void setJSONString(String data) {
    jsonBody = data;
}

private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();

    // Setting 30 second timeouts
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30 * 1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30 * 1000);

    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            response = convertStreamToString(instream);

            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

JSON is easy to construct and easy to implement as compared to XML.

Here is code snippets for [Executing a HTTP POST Request with HttpClient](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

Here is the best Question with Answer given: [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505930/379693)

[Calling a REST web service from Android](http://timewasted.net/?p=127)

### Update:

This one suits your requirement to make a REST webservice call with JSON request: [calling rest web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247402/calling-rest-web-service/5247749#5247749)

Comment: thanks..  Can u give me some other resource where i can get some basic information of android web services.. just basic and beginner web service information! Thanks